# Yii2 - Display ads on protected pages (amnah/yii2-user)

Tags: yii2, adsense, google-crawlers

I have a website done with Yii2 and the extension "[amnah / yii2-user](https://github.com/amnah/yii2-user)"
And I am trying to follow the instructions on the link below to publish ads on the members page. However I am unable to validate the data.

Can anyone give me an example of how I should fill in the fields?

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/161351?hl=en

http://www.webnots.com/adsense-crawler-access-to-password-protected-pages/

**EDIT**

I tried this:

*Restricted url - http://example.com/user/profile

Login url - http://example.com/user/login

Login method - POST

Parameter - LoginForm[email]

Parameter - LoginForm[password]*

The message below in the PARAMETER field:

```
These characters are not allowed: [,]
```

[image]

Comment: What data you can't validate? My first guess is about something related to CSRF stuff.

Comment: I edited with the error message

Comment: Try to encode form field names, e.g. `LoginForm%5Bemail%5D` instead of `LoginForm[email]`.